# Help identify the pattern for reacting on updates

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns

There's an entity that gets updated from external sources. Update events are at random intervals. And the entity has to be processed once updated. Multiple updates may be multiplexed. In other words there's a need for the most current state of entity to be processed.

There's a point of no-return during processing where the current state (and the state is consistent i.e. no partial update is made) of entity is saved somewhere else and processing goes on independently of any arriving updates.

Every consequent set of updates has to trigger processing i.e. system should not forget about updates. And for each entity there should be no more than one running processing (before the point of no-return) i.e. the entity state should not be processed more than once.

So what I'm looking for is a pattern to cancel current processing before the point of no return or abandon processing results if an update arrives. The main challenge is to minimize race conditions and maintain integrity.

The entity sits mainly in database with some files on disk. And the system is in .NET with web-services and message queues.

What comes to my mind is a database queue-like table. An arriving update inserts row in that table and the processing is launched. The processing gathers necessary data before the point of no-return and once it reaches this barrier it looks into the queue table and checks whether there're more recent updates for the entity. If there are new updates the processing simply shuts down and its data is discarded. Otherwise the processing data is persisted and it goes beyond the point of no-return.

Though it looks like a solution to me it is not quite elegant and I believe this scenario may be supported by some sort of middleware.

If I would use message queues for this then there's a need to access the queue API in the point of no-return to check for the existence of new messages. And this approach also lacks elegance.

Is there a name for this pattern and an existing solution?

Comment: I think you might be thinking of database transactions.  Up to the point at which you actually COMMIT a transaction, you can ROLLBACK and it undoes the work accomplished up to that point.

Comment: @Robert: Probably no because the processing takes at least minutes to complete. It would lock a lot of resources in database in that case.

Comment: The problem reminds me an optimistic locking: take the data in memory, make a copy and change the copy in memory, keep original untouched, then go back to the database and compare the original against the database. If the data did not change you may apply your changes, otherwise discard it.

Comment: This sounds very much like a good fit for event sourcing. https://github.com/eventstore/eventstore/wiki/Event-Sourcing-Basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement the pattern largely following Jimmy Hoffa's advice and ideas.
The pattern works for us for several months already and it works as follows.

1. Every time the Entity is updated we insert new row to the EntityRevision table. This table has autoincrement (identity) RevisionId field which we pass along to the Pre-Processing.
2. During Pre-Processing we extract the state of Entity associated with the RevisionId being processed and work with it. The point here is that we avoid using any queries that return current Entity state because it’s constantly changing as Entity is updated. In contrast the state associated with the Revision never changes and it’s safe to use it during concurrent updates.
3. The Entity’s RevisionId is sent to offline processing Queue after Pre-Processing. We use the following rules.
   Say arrived RevisionId is equal to X

   a) If there’s no other Revision for the same Entity in the Queue, we add X to the Queue
   b) If there’s already RevisionId which is Y for the same Entity in the Queue:

   - if Y > X, we discard X. In other words we don’t need earlier Revision X to be processed offline.
   - if X > Y, we remove Y from Queue and X to Queue. Since Y is earlier than X, we replace it with X.

   We make operations on the Queue to perform in serial order so that at most one process/thread alters the queue at any time. For now we use Mutex in the Queue operations.
4. The Offline Processing polls the Queue on a periodical schedule and does what it needs to do with Revisions in the Queue. Again we use here only state of Entity associated with its Revision.

   While we guarantee that there’s the current Revision in the Queue pre-processed so far, we are still not protected from the same Entity being updated or update being pre-processed during or right after the ongoing Offline Processing. In such case an update will have to wait in the Queue for the next Offline Processing launch. But that’s ok, we can’t prohibit updates :) In fact those updates are the essence of the system.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the "point-of-no-return" processor from the pre-setup piece. One service picks up the updates and does whatever setup to get ready for offline processing, and then before handing it over to the offline processor just checks either the database or if it's on a single machine you could use signals, in .NET [EventWaitHandles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) named for the entity ID to see if any new updates came in. If so, the pre-processor just goes back to start with the new updates pulled in as it gets everything ready again for the offline processor. Each time it gets to offline processing point it does this check.

Comment: 1) The module which single responsibility is to make atomic check for cancellation or atomic advancement after the point of no-return is certainly a good thing to have. Consulting to this module along the processing pipeline would allow to either cancel the processing as early as possible or to safely go to offline mode. The system is potentially distributed and so the named signals is not an option. Here the database you mentioned would work.

Comment: 2) The system is more complex, there are certain steps that group entities and make processing of group as a whole and it's made before the point of no-return. In order those steps to be simple there's a need to complicate that check point module so it would know different kinds of processing and what it is going on in the system. While I realize that I would love to know how to build this kind of thing. And may be this complicated check point module or orchestrator is totally wrong way to go I don't know.

Comment: @Mike You're describing a state machine for which a single orchestrator is usually a good idea. The important thing to remember is the orchestrator should be stateless, and not know the details of the processing. The only way to make that work is that any processing specific information the orchestrator needs are exposed by the modules which know that processing logic. The orchestrator get's a request to move a group to a new state, it know for that state the groups need to have a fourteenSidedOblogon, so the orchestrator calls serviceX.HasFourteenSidedOblogon with the group.

Comment: @Mike good description and further reading at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine also here's a .NET simple state machine library that may be useful at least for giving you ideas about how to structure this orchestration piece http://code.google.com/p/stateless/ notice how it has onEntry/onExit criteria that are given to it rather than the orchestrator having the knowledge inherently.

Comment: Funny thing I've recently started using a state machine in this project in the update initiating phase and it's from [Appccelerate](http://www.appccelerate.com/statemachine.html). But what worries me is that the state machine has to operate on the state and that state should be taken from the database if it has to be shared by several processes or may be passed as a message if it does not. And when it has to be shared what component is responsible for loading and storing the state in the database? And by the way what's Oblogon?

Comment: @Mike Oblogon n. def: A thing that sounds like a thing but isn't anything at all. :) Responsibility for storage should be any repository/data providers you have, but the responsibility for calling those to store the new state is the machine; it is the only thing which is allowed to alter the *state* but should know none of the logic for and not be allowed to alter the entity, it should delegate that to services/modules responsible for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

> The processing gathers necessary data before the point of no-return and once it reaches this barrier it looks into the queue table and checks whether there're more recent updates for the entity. If there are new updates the processing simply shuts down and its data is discarded. Otherwise the processing data is persisted and it goes beyond the point of no-return.

Depending on the frequency of updates received, the system can enter on periods of starvation - where the just-processed updates are discarded continuously because new ones are being received.

Instead of throwing away the computations, you can just keep an stack of the outputs generated.

Take a look at LMAX Architecture: http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

Comment: I recognize that there would be peroids of starvation for some entites. But such periods are supposed to take up to 1% of entity lifetime in the worst case. The system meanwhile may process other entities updates concurrently.
I like your idea of stack and the LMAX architecutre is inspiring, however I still can't figure out how to combine those things together. Can you share your insights?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're okay with limiting your data repository options to Microsoft SQL Server, you could opt to go with using [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb522893%28SQL.105%29.aspx) to handle your messaging & queuing.

Since this would all be encapsulated within the database engine, there wouldn't need to be any sort of external API calls from the point of no-return check either. All of the logic could be written into stored procedures (either with T-SQL or as CLR procedures). Also, with [Service Broker Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you can have other programs (e.g. your own executable) run on-demand, whenever there's work for it to do.

As an added bonus, Service Broker is easily scalable, so you can offload any data processing to another server(s) & keep your primary database server from being bogged down by any irregular data processing loads - just setup your multiple instances & point Service Broker to the [appropriate endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166060%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

However, some of the drawbacks of using Service Broker are:

- Additional learning curve for developers (learning a new technology).
- More complicated to troubleshoot for any non-DBA type tech support.
- Requires [Standard Edition or higher (with SQL Server 2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Programmability) - not available with the Express Edition (i.e. the free version).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the Service Broker. But I don't think I'll go this direction. While it appears to solve data consistency issues the Service Broker does not provide direct pattern to solution of the problem. It introduces lock-in on SQL Server and requires additional training however I would prefer more independent approach.